# Hive trying to read current working directory when called in Python script

Tags: python, hive, subprocess

I am attempting to execute a Hive script from a Python wrapper. Part of code looks like

```
print(HiveArgs)
Hive = subprocess.Popen(HiveArgs, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
HiveOutput = Hive.communicate()

print("Out:" + HiveOutput[0])
print("=================================")
print("Err:" + HiveOutput[1])
```

The output of this is:

```
['hive', '-i ', '/edw/edwdev/tmp/spark.txn.init.tmp', '-f ', '/edw/edwdev/tmp/test.hql.tmp']
Out:
=================================
Err:
Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.5.0.2-3/0/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/data/edw/edwdev/  does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:850)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:782)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processInitFiles(CliDriver.java:439)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:684)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:624)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
```

where `/data/edw/edwdev/` (file that Hive thinks is missing) is my working directory on a Linux server.

Changing working directory to script's location doesn't help. Using relative and absolute paths also makes no difference. If i copy values from the printed `HiveArgs` and execute the command from terminal (`hive -i /edw/edwdev/tmp/spark.txn.init.tmp -f /edw/edwdev/tmp/test.hql.tmp`), it works correctly.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why is `/data/edw/edwdev/` directory different than the one you use in args `/edw/edwdev/tmp/spark.txn.init.tmp` ?  `/data` prefix is surplus?

Comment: `/edw/` is a soft link to `/data/edw/`. However, the issue remains if the working directory is totally different, e.g. `/home/edwdev` or even `/`

Comment: have you tried adding the directory to environment variable?

Comment: @pankajmishra which directory do you mean? Working directory or some else? I can try that but the Python wrapper will eventually be executed from crontab, I don't know if adding directory to path will work there. Also, I don't see how the working directory is even relevant for this; its.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the issue was with Hive arguments.`print(HiveArgs)` line gave output:

```
['hive', '-i ', '/edw/edwdev/tmp/spark.txn.init.tmp', '-f ', '/edw/edwdev/tmp/test.hql.tmp']
```

The arguments passed are `'-f '` and `'-i '` (with trailing spaces) instead of `'-f'` and `'-i'`.

I am not sure what caused the issue within Hive leading it to read current working directory as some input file. Most likely Hive does not trim the arguments leading to this behavior. Removing the spaces fixed the issue.